# get modified files after given timestamp in windows file system in Cpp code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, filesystems, last-modified

Is there any way that I can get `modified files/folders` after a `given timestamp` in `windows file system`? I don't want to traverse entire file system and check which file/folder is modified in my code. Does windows provide any API which returns modified files/folders after a given time stamp ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no direct WinAPI to accomplish this.

I'd suggest traversing only through certain folders (exclude folders like `Windows`, `ProgramData`) etc. Traverse only through the folders that make sense. **ex**: `Users`.

Why? Because the system files in `Windows` and such folders are accessed very frequently and are modified after system updates. Unless you're keen to see when the system files were modified, I'd say the data is going to be irrelevant and of no meaning.